# How can i force an option menu to show up on android?

Tags: android

I have created an option menu for my app, but i want it to show up at the application start and be never hidden by any user control.

How can I?  Is there a solution or i have to draw a custom menu in the layout?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I?

Don't make it an options menu. Use buttons or something.

If you want something to look like an options menu, please have it *behave* like an options menu, appearing when the user presses MENU and disappearing when the user makes a choice. Conversely, if you do not want it to behave like an options menu, then it should not look like an options menu, as that will confuse the user, wondering why your application or their phone is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place it in your layout.

Comment: You cannot place an options menu in a layout, per se.

Comment: Of course; I didn't mean a literal options menu... I meant he would have to draw something custom, as he mentioned. Buttons / whatever.